# Parsing identifiers in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to match identifiers in ANTLR4 and it seems to be cutting them off after some time. Here is the relevant part of my grammer:

```
prog: (EOL)* statements;
statements: statement (EOL)+ (statement (EOL)+)* ;
statement : declaration ;
declaration : mutability ' '+ ident ' '* assign_operator ' '* expression ;
block : '{' statements '}';
expression : ident
           | number ;
EOL : '\n' ;
mutability : ('let'|'var') ;
assign_operator : '=' ;
number : ('-'?(DIGIT|'_')+('.')?(DIGIT|'_')*('e''-'?)?(DIGIT|'_')*) ;
ident : ('_'|LETTER) ('_'|LETTER|DIGIT)* ;
DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
LETTER : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ;
```

and here are my test cases:

```
let _1 = 5
let _12 = 5
let _123 = 5
let _1234 = 5
let _12345 = 5
let _123456 = 5
let _1234567 = 5
let _12345678 = 5
let _123456789 = 5
let _1234567890 = 5

let a = 5
let ab = 5
let abc = 5
let abcd = 5
let abcde = 5
let abcdef = 5
```

It works for everything but the last two statements. It give me

```
line 33:8 no viable alternative at input 'let abcde'
line 34:8 no viable alternative at input 'let abcde'
```

for them and fails to parse them. I don't understand why it works if I start with an _ and use a bunch of numbers but it fails after the same number of letters every time.

Comment: What does a dump of the token stream show you? Which tokens did your lexer return for the test input?

Comment: OOOHHHH! I has this line: `'e'=45` because of how I want to allow scientific notation! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I guess I can then post this as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the token stream output. Usually these kind of problems arise from wrong tokens generated by the lexer.